# Python replace error: replace() argument 2 must be str, not Series

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace

I want to update a string with html code. The string is something like this:

```
textHTMLextract = 'Hello, my name is name1 name2'
```

And I have a dataframe with variables like this:

```
import pandas as pd
variables = [{'Var': 'name1', 'Value': '<i>John</i>'}, 
             {'Var':'name2', 'Value': '<i><b>Smith</b></i>'}] 
df_variables = pd.DataFrame(variables)
```

The idea is to replace the string with some html tagged values.
I've tried by transforming the dataframe into a dict and then replace through a for loop:

```
vars_dict = dict(df_variables)

for key, value in vars_dict.items():
   textHTMLextract = textHTMLextract.replace(key, value)
```

I expect the code to return

```
'Hello, my name is <i>John</i> <i><b>Smith</b></i>'
```

to eventually be printed in the html intepreter as

'Hello, my name is *John* ***Smith***'

But all I get is the error message below:

```
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not Series
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using pandas here, you can leverage `Series.replace` which takes a dictionary of replacements and works with regex:

```
mappings = dict(zip(df['Var'], df['Value']))
pd.Series(textHTMLextract).replace(mappings, regex=True).item()
# 'Hello, my name is <i>John</i> <i><b>Smith</b></i>'
```

Comment: Excelent! Worked! Nevertheless, the Python console warns future deprecation of item(): FutureWarning: `item` has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. An alternative to item I've found is using   'next(iter(pd.Series(textHTMLextract).replace(mappings, regex=True)))'